# GCC is not linking library to a non-default path

Tags: gcc, boost, linker, g++

I have boost C++ libraries already installed on my Fedora10 machine but I want to use a newer version that I keep at some location in my home folder. I want g++ to use include and library files from my home folder location instead of default (`/usr/include and /usr/lib64`).

For that matter, I also have declared `CPLUS\_INCLUDE\_PATH and LIBRARY\_PATH` environment variables in my `~/.bashrc` file as explained [here](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_23.html).

Now when I run,

```
g++ -o hello.so -fPIC hello.cpp -shared -lboost_python
```

The preprocessor uses include files from my home folder location, overriding the default location (as it should, because `CPLUS\_INCLUDE\_PATH` has a higher precedence in the search path). But the linker does not seem to follow the same precedence rule. It always uses libboost_python.so from the default location `/usr/lib64` instead of first searching `LIBRARY\_PATH`. It only links to the `libboost\_python.so` library in my home folder when I explicitly specify with `-L` switch. This is really inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

The `-L` switch is the standard way of telling the compiler where to find the libraries. Write a makefile that builds your compiler/linker switches - you'll find it's worth investing your time. You can do something like:

```
MY_LIBPATH += -L$(BOOST_LIB_PATH)
MY_INCPATH += -I$(BOOST_INC_PATH)
hello.so: hello.cpp
    g++ -o $@ -fPIC $(MY_INCPATH) $(MY_LIBPATH) hello.cpp -shared -lboost_python
```

And then you can control this via environment (of course there could be many variations on how to structure the makefile.)